# Can anyone help me use PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell

I want to setup the below functionality using Powershell Invoke-RestMethod

1. Get token from an exposed RestAPI .
2. Check Authentication using the received token .
3. If Authentication is correct send in some data in Body including Header information .

I have the below info with me , could anyone help me as I don't have much experience with RestMethod calling .

To get Token:
*http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/test/getToken*
Method: GET

Response: 1fd640d0-b4fc-4b95-a27c-e61b7cb3a44f

To Post Data: 
*http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/test/postData*
Method: POST

Header Param:

```
X-Access-Token: 1fd640d0-b4fc-4b95-a27c-e61b7cb3a44f
```

Sample Request:

```
{
            "id": 2,
            "cid": "TEST",
            "concurrent_users": 10,
            "view_version": "7.0.3",
            "timestamp": "2016:12:12:22:00",
            "pool_details": [{
                            "id": 12,
                            "pool_name": "Test_Pool",
                            "active_dtps": 10,
                            "provisioned_dtps": 10
            }, {
                            "id": 12,
                            "pool_name": "Test_Pool",
                            "active_dtps": 10,
                            "provisioned_dtps": 10
            }]
}
```

Sample Response:

```
{
            "id": 2,
            "cid": "TEST",
            "concurrent_users": 10,
            "view_version": "5.3.4",
            "timestamp": "2016:12:12:22:00",
            "pool_details": [{
                            "id": 12,
                            "pool_name": "Test_Pool",
                            "active_dtps": 10,
                            "provisioned_dtps": 10
            }, {
                            "id": 12,
                            "pool_name": "Test_Pool",
                            "active_dtps": 10,
                            "provisioned_dtps": 10
            }]
}
```

Comment: I am new with Invoke-RestMethod and so I haven't tried much , want someone who could help me with a sample coding for the same .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an answer and it works perfectly .

```
$token_url = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/test/getToken"
$username = "varun"
$password = "password"

$post_data_url = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/test/postData"

$pool = (
@{
    id = 12
    pool_name = "Test_Pool"
    active_dtps = 10
    provisioned_dtps = 10
},
@{
    id = 2
    cid = "TEST"
    concurrent_users = 10
    view_version = "10.25"
    timestamp = "2016:12:12:22:00"
    pool_details = $pool
}
)

$request = @{
id = 2
cid = "TEST"
concurrent_users = 10
view_version = "10.25"
timestamp = "2016:12:12:22:00"
pool_details = $pool # | ConvertTo-Json
}

$json = $request | ConvertTo-Json

$token = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $token_url -Headers @{ "Authorization" = "username=$username;password=$password"}

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $post_data_url -Headers @{ "X-Access-Token" = "$token"} -ContentType 'application/json' -Body $json 

$result
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
$token = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/test/getToken"    
Write-Host $token

$data = @{ 
    id=2
    cid="TEST"
    concurrent_users=10
    view_version="7.0.3"
    timestamp="2016:12:12:22:00"
    pool_details=@(
        { id=12; pool_name="Test_Pool"; active_dtps=10; provisioned_dtps=10 },
        { id=12; pool_name="Test_Pool"; active_dtps=10; provisioned_dtps=10 }
        ) 
    } 
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/test/postData" -Method Post -Headers @{'X-Access-Token'=$token} -Body $data
Write-Hot $response
```

Comment: Thanks @craig for the response , I did test this , it needs few amendments .  
1) The Body part would have to be converted to a method (JSON/HTML) so I did use JSON in my case as it is more popular in use .
2) It needs to add Header in the Get Token part
3) It also needs to add -Body type in the Post method .